# Get last modified time in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, performance, file, time, timestamp

I am using the following code to dynamically add scripts in JavaScript:

```
function loadJS(file, c, preventCache)
{
    var jsEl = document.createElement("script");
    if (typeof preventCache === 'undefined' || !preventCache)
        jsEl.src = file;
    else
        jsEl.src = file + "?" + Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000));
    if (c) { jsEl.addEventListener('load', function (e) { c(null, e); }, false); }
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(jsEl);
}
```

Appending `"?" + Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000))` disables caching altogether. What I would like to do instead, is append a time stamp of the last modified time of the file. Then the file can be cached but only when it is up to date. How can I efficiently get the last modified time of the file?

Comment: If you set cache control headers properly, the browser should do this automatically. It can use the `If-Modified-Since` request header to download the file only if it has been changed since the cached version.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it's not possible:
[Is it possible with javascript to find file's last modified time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5746598/is-it-possible-with-javascript-to-find-files-last-modified-time)

But there are more efficient ways than a random number. You can use a version number like WordPress does, or use something that changes less regularly (every hour, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

The file that contains the `loadJS`, already contains a timestamp generated in PHP. I've decided to include in that file a variable containing the last time any script was modified. I can automate all of that in PHP, considering the JavaScript files are modified from within my website. To do this I will use `file_get_contents`, modify the line with a  timestamp, then `file_put_contents`. This may seem extremely inefficient but considering, only I will be able to modify JavaScript files and none of my clients will, then I guess it will suffice.